# Visual Basic Saving Form info on hide

Tags: winforms, vba, visual-studio-2008

Im using Visual Basic 2008

I have 2 forms
Main, EditCustomerInfo

Main form contains the following

```
 Public Class Main

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)   Handles Button1.Click
    EditCustomerInfo.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

EditCustomerInfo contains  a text box and the following

```
 Public Class EditCustomerInfo

  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)   Handles Button1.Click

  If Not CustomerIDTextBox.Text = "" Then
        Me.Close()

    Else : Me.Hide()
    End If

End Sub
```

WHAT IT DOES:
So with this code alone when i debug the program it takes me to the main form and allows me to click a button to open the editcustomerinfo form

When im on the editcustomerinfo form i have a textbox and a button. If something is typed in the textbox and the button is clicked then the form hides, if nothing is typed in the textbox when the button is clicked then the form closes.

WHAT I WOULD LIKE IT TO DO:
If something is typed in the textbox i would like the button on the editcustomerinfoform to hide the editcustomerinfoform and also create a button on main form that allows the user to bring the editcustomerinfo form back up with what was typed in the text box.

Suggestions?

Comment: What do i need to clarify? I dont see why i was downvoted.

Comment: I dont know who gave you down vote, but your question seems decent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic behavior, such as this, always worries me. How do you know when a user has completed their input without a lost focus event. If there are no other controls on the screen, then users won't readily know how to trigger the event. That being said, you can use a timer to delay the screen closing from a KeyPress event.

```
Public Class EditCustomerInfo
    Private WithEvents userInputDelay As Timer = New Timer() With {.Interval = 1000} REM 1 second delay for next user input
    Public ReadOnly Property CustomerId As String
        Get
            Return CustomerIDTextBox.Text
        End Get
    End Property
    Private Sub CustomerIDTextBox_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles CustomerIDTextBox.KeyPress
        userInputDelay.Enabled = False
        REM Reset the timer
        userInputDelay.Enabled = True

    End Sub
    Private Sub userInputDelay_Tick(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles userInputDelay.Tick
        If Not CustomerIDTextBox.Text = "" Then
            Me.Close()

        Else : Me.Hide()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Add a button (Button2) to your Main. The code below will hide Button1 when the EditCustomerInfo.Textbox1.Text value is null/blank/white space. Button2's visibility is always the inverse of Button1.

```
Private EditCustomerInfoInstance As New EditCustomerInfo

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    EditCustomerInfoInstance.ShowDialog()
    Button1.Visible = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(EditCustomerInfoInstance.CustomerId)
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_VisibleChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.VisibleChanged
    Button2.Visible = Not Button1.Visible
End Sub
```